# how different is the notion of an "indeterminate" from that of "algebraically independent" in relation to dimension theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

The following is a well-known theorem in commutative algebra, see e.g. Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, p. 117:

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ indeterminates over $A$. Then $\dim A[X_1,\cdots,X_n] = \dim A + n$.

Question: I am trying to understand what exactly is meant by "indeterminates". Certainly, if the $X_i$ are indeterminate, then they are algebraically independent over $A$. Is the converse true? i.e. if $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are elements in some ring extension of $A$ such that they are algebraically independent over $A$, then can we view them as indeterminates over $A$? If $A$ is a field, then certainly $\dim A[a_1,\cdots,a_n]=tr.deg_A A[a_1,\cdots,a_n] = n = \dim A + n$ and so the statement of the theorem holds. What if $A$ is not a field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these are the same thing. One difficulty in seeing that this is so is that one might not have a tangible definition of "indeterminate". To remedy this, define the free commutative $A$-algebra on $n$ generators to be a commutative $A$-algebra $B$ with elements $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ such that, given another commutative $A$-algebra $C$ and choice of elements $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ in $C$, there is a unique $A$-algebra hom $B\to C$ such that $X_i\to c_i$. Then it's not hard to prove that "algebraically independent" and "indeterminate" are the same thing.